# What is the correct changes I should make to my if statement to make it activate?

Tags: c

Currently I have a code that passes arguments to main and I use the strstr tool to see if the arguments or strings passed to it are subsets of each other. If they are not, I get the message (null). However, when I try to take advantage of this with an if statement it doesn't seem to activate?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<argc; i++) 
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    char *chant;
    chant = strstr(argv[1], argv[2]);
    printf("The subtring is: %s\n", chant);
    if(chant==NULL)
    {
       printf("good bye");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So if I enter something like hello helloow, it will say "The substring is: (null)" and from there I want my if statement to activate and print "good bye". Isn't chant NULL when strstr can't find a substring? I know there is something wrong with my if statement syntax, but not sure >....

I have tried this as well:

```
if(*chant!=NULL)
```

but it gives me this comparison error about pointer and integer.

EDIT:

I don't know WHY, but it seems that if I use GCC instead of CC to comnpile then it will work.. This is very odd..

Comment: You get the error because `*chant` *is* and integer and in C `NULL` is usually a pointer (it's usually defined as a macro with a body of `((void *) 0)`). You want to check e.g. `if (chant != NULL)`, i.e. drop the dereference operator `*`.

Comment: And now I see that you *have* that check, but after it's needed.

Comment: I am a little bit lost, sorry, so I should try if (chant != NULL)?

Comment: I dropped it, but the if statement doesn't activate >.<.

Comment: for me it works: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77c7342eb325fa91

Comment: Wait, you mean drop the * in the if statement or for the char *chant?

Comment: What int he world, why is it working for you >.>.. I am doing this on terminal for ubuntu..

Comment: are you compiling exactly this code? Assure this & try again.

Comment: Yes for sure, I am double checking everything with yours and mine.. Hmm -_-. Might the compiler version affect anything? I am running the latest ubuntu,

Comment: Edit.. I switched from using cc to gcc to compile and it worked.. what the hell -_-.

Answer (score 3):

`printf()` expects a valid (non-NULL) `char*` matching the `%s`. Passing a `(char*)NULL` is *technically* undefined behaviour. glibc `printf()`, for probably bad reasons, decides that "undefined behaviour" to them means printing "(null)".
But the C-compiler sees you dereference a pointer, and then **afterwards** check whether it was NULL. The compiler is free to conclude that, since you've already dereferenced that pointer, and the world hasn't ended, that pointer *wasn't* NULL, so it removes the `if(!chant){//can't happen}`.
 Welcome to C.
To get defined behaviour, you could go with code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     //to avoid passing a NULL-ptr to printf()/strstr()
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<argc; i++) 
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    char *chant;
    chant = strstr(argv[1], argv[2]);
    printf("The subtring is: %s\n", chant?chant:"(null)");
        //prints "(null)" when substring not found, substring otherwise
    if(chant==NULL)
    {
       printf("good bye");
    }
    return 0;
}
```